# Gracefully stopping a build step (plugin) on build abort

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a plugin in Jenkins that operates a remote server via rest.
How can I send one last request to the server on build abort? Thus, gracefully finishing the work of the plugin?

The only reference to the 'Abort sequence' that I found is [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build).
Which makes me think that the procedure is very rough, and that I can't catch the signal before it terminates the child (my plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar need, which I solved with the [PostBuildScript Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin).

I choose to run a build step, but you can run several other options. Very easy to use.
I have a script I must run regardless of how the build ended (success, fail or abort). It works great for me.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really disappointed that this is the only answer. Thanks for the effort, I will reward you the bounty soon if no last callers come.

Answer (score 2):

When the build is aborted, an `InterruptedException` is thrown. You can catch it like any other exception, and not only gracefully exit, but prevent the abort, if you so wish.

In your `boolean perform()` method, set up a

```
try {
 ... // Whatever your plugin does
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Code to handle build being aborted.
}
```

statement, which will handle any aborts that occur while your build step is being run. In the `catch` statement you can then throw an `InterruptedException` again to continue aborting the build, or just return and let the build continue.