# Catch Abort signal on hudson in shell script?

Tags: hudson

How can we trap the abort signal of the job on hudson so that i can do some post steps in case of abort (I am running a job on hudson which has shell script running in background)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gracefully stopping a build step (plugin) on build abort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119727/gracefully-stopping-a-build-step-plugin-on-build-abort)

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced with Jenkins, not hudson, (Jenkins is a fork of hudson) Jenkins sends a SIGTERM on Unix through Sun's JRE java.lang.UnixProcess.destroyProcess, on Windows, this is done through TerminateProcess API.

[JENKINS - Aborting a build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build)

[HUDSON - Aborting a build](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Aborting+a+build)

So you can use "trap" in your shell script by this way

```
#!/bin/bash

getAbort()
{
 echo "Abort detected"
 # other commands here if any...
} 

trap 'getAbort; exit' SIGTERM
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer but my problem is specific to the hudson

Comment: Jenkins is a fork of Hudson, so probably sends the same signal on abort jobs, test it.

Comment: I found that `getAbort()` needed to be defined before the trap command.  (Possibly because I didn't bother with `#!/bin/bash`.)

Comment: You are right,  the functions needs to be defined before call it, my mistake.